# What fonts are actually available for MATLAB graphics text?

Tags: matlab, fonts

Supposedly, the MATLAB library function listfonts returns the available system fonts, and listTrueTypeFonts returns the available TrueType fonts.  On my Mac, both of these claim "ZapfDingbats" is available.  However, Microsoft Word doesn't list it as available, there's no such file in /Library/Fonts, it's not listed in /Library/Fonts/fonts.dir, and when I try to use it with text(), I get Arial.

Is there something wrong with my font configuration?
If MATLAB has cached the wrong information, can that be updated?
How else can a MATLAB program tell what is actually available?

Comment: This is not Mac-specific, I get the same result on R2016b/Windows 7. The answer in the linked duplicate question suggests that `listfonts` always includes the "standard" PostScript font set, for what I guess are long-since-obsolete historical reasons.